# Creating RadioButtons from an enum in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums, radio-button

I'd like to populate a `StackPanel` with `RadioButton` objects which correspond to the values of an enum. Each button's handler should run an arbitrary computation which takes the corresponding enum val.

Here's the method I came up with:

```
void EnumToRadioButtonPanel(Panel panel, Type type, Action<int> proc)
{
    Array.ForEach((int[])Enum.GetValues(type),
        val =>
        {
            var button = new RadioButton() { Content = Enum.GetName(type, val) };
            button.Click += (s, e) => proc(val);
            panel.Children.Add(button);
        });
}
```

For example, let's say I want `RadioButton`s for the enum `FigureHorizontalAnchor`. I'd like the action of each button to set the `HorizontalAnchor` property of a particular `Figure` called `figure`. Here's how I'd invoke `EnumToRadioButtonPanel`:

```
var figure = new Figure();

var stackPanel = new StackPanel();

EnumToRadioButtonPanel(stackPanel, typeof(FigureHorizontalAnchor),
    val =>
    {
        figure.HorizontalAnchor = (FigureHorizontalAnchor)
            Enum.ToObject(typeof(FigureHorizontalAnchor), val);
    });
```

My question is, is there a better way to accomplish this? Should I be using "binding" techniques instead? I've seen a couple of related questions here on SO, but they involved laying out the `RadioButton`s in XAML; I'd like to do this via the code behind in C#.

Here's a complete runnable demo of the above. XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EnumToRadioButtonPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace EnumToRadioButtonPanel
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        void EnumToRadioButtonPanel(Panel panel, Type type, Action<int> proc)
        {
            Array.ForEach((int[])Enum.GetValues(type),
                val =>
                {
                    var button = new RadioButton() { Content = Enum.GetName(type, val) };
                    button.Click += (s, e) => proc(val);
                    panel.Children.Add(button);
                });
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var figure = new Figure();

            var stackPanel = new StackPanel();

            Content = stackPanel;

            EnumToRadioButtonPanel(stackPanel, typeof(FigureHorizontalAnchor),
                val =>
                {
                    figure.HorizontalAnchor = (FigureHorizontalAnchor)
                        Enum.ToObject(typeof(FigureHorizontalAnchor), val);
                });

            var label = new Label();

            stackPanel.Children.Add(label);

            var button = new Button() { Content = "Display" };

            button.Click += (s, e) => label.Content = figure.HorizontalAnchor;

            stackPanel.Children.Add(button);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you suggest, there is more "WPF" ways to do it.

Do not create controls by code. It was somewhat ok with *WinForms*, but it's not how you wanna do it in *WPF*.

If you want to create a collection of controls out of a list of item, use `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl Source="{Binding ItemsIWantToCreateControlsFor}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <RadioButton
        Content="{Binding APropertyDefinedInMyItem}"
        Command="{Binding ACommandDefinedInMyItemThatIsExecutedWhenPressed}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas. Thanks for the tips. Doing this from C# is a requirement though. I'd also like to aim for the API specified in my question. I.e. populate a panel given an enum. So I'm going to hold off on accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of `EnumToRadioButtonPanel` which seems to lead to cleaner code by being generic over the type.

```
void EnumToRadioButtonPanel<T>(Panel panel, Action<T> proc)
{
    Array.ForEach((int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)),
        val =>
        {
            var button = new RadioButton() { Content = Enum.GetName(typeof(T), val) };
            button.Click += (s, e) => proc((T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T),val));
            panel.Children.Add(button);
        });
}
```

With this version, the call to `EnumToRadioButtonPanel` looks like this:

```
EnumToRadioButtonPanel<FigureHorizontalAnchor>(
    stackPanel,
    val => figure.HorizontalAnchor = val);
```

instead of:

```
EnumToRadioButtonPanel(stackPanel, typeof(FigureHorizontalAnchor),
    val =>
    {
        figure.HorizontalAnchor = (FigureHorizontalAnchor)
            Enum.ToObject(typeof(FigureHorizontalAnchor), val);
    });
```

Below is the entire example. XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EnumToRadioButtonPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace EnumToRadioButtonPanel
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        void EnumToRadioButtonPanel<T>(Panel panel, Action<T> proc)
        {
            Array.ForEach((int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)),
                val =>
                {
                    var button = new RadioButton() { Content = Enum.GetName(typeof(T), val) };
                    button.Click += (s, e) => proc((T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T),val));
                    panel.Children.Add(button);
                });
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var figure = new Figure();

            var stackPanel = new StackPanel();

            Content = stackPanel;

            EnumToRadioButtonPanel<FigureHorizontalAnchor>(
                stackPanel,
                val => figure.HorizontalAnchor = val);

            var label = new Label();

            stackPanel.Children.Add(label);

            var button = new Button() { Content = "Display" };

            button.Click += (s, e) => label.Content = figure.HorizontalAnchor;

            stackPanel.Children.Add(button);
        }
    }
}
```